# Como alterar o valor de diversas variáveis do mesmo tipo, para o mesmo valor, de uma única vez?

Tags: c#, variáveis, unity3d

Queria saber se há alguma forma de se alterar diversas variáveis do tipo `bool` para o mesmo valor, `true` ou `false`, de uma única vez? Tenho vários métodos que são parecidos e fazem a mesma coisa, só que com diferentes variáveis, e queria uma alternativa para este problema.

```
void resetStage()
    {
        _fullLife = false;
        _halfLife = false;
        _almostDead = false;
    }
```

Por exemplo, um método onde eu passaria as três variáveis, _fullLife, _halfLife e _amostDead como parâmetros, e este método alteraria seus valores para false, ou true, caso eu desejasse. Porém, caso eu o quisesse utilizar este método em outro código, com outras variáveis e com a quantidade de parâmetros que eu quisesse não me causasse nenhum problema.

Pensei em algo como:

```
void boolReset(bool resetTo, params bool[] valueBool)
    {
        valueBool.All(x => x = resetTo);
    }
```

Mas percebi que não funcionaria pois, estaria passando os valores das variáveis, e não teria como as utilizar como referência.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A primeira coisa que tem que avaliar sobre isso é entender o processo de desenvolvimento de software e como escrever códigos. Um código deve expressar bem o que está fazendo de forma clara e objetiva. Ser curto é uma característica boa, ser curto demais, ser esquisito, usar truques para parecer curto não é uma característica boa.

Dito isso, não vejo problema algum no que fez originalmente, esse código está simples e claro, expressa bem o que deve fazer, é organizado e facilitará a manutenção no futuro.

Se tentar fazer algo que fuja disso ficará um código esquisito e poderá trazer problemas no futuro. Você pode estar começando e não ter essa visão clara, eu faço isto há mais de 35 anos, e já tentei fazer tudo o mais curto possível. Hoje eu vejo os erros que cometi.

Dá para reduzir ligeiramente:

```
void resetStage() {
    _fullLife = _halfLife = _almostDead = false;
}
```

Não gosto disso porque gera efeito colateral, mudança de estado, e é melhor deixar isto explícito e claro. Mudança de estado é o que tem de pior em um código, quase todos problemas sérios de algoritmo estão relacionados com mudança de estado. Inclusive em alguns casos pode dificultar o processo de *debug*. Mas é o máximo que deveria fazer.

Acho que deveria ler sobre o [DRY](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101). Muitas pessoas acham que é sobre escrever menos código. O DRY é sobre ser canônico e não sobre escrever menos. Escrever menos código só é bom quando o código é desnecessário ou claramente repetitivo, não é o seu caso, este código esta ótimo para todos padrões conhecidos. Tentar algo que parece mais simples na verdade é complicar mais, é expressar o código da forma errada, e código é expressão.

> Qualquer idiota pode escrever código que um computador entenda. Bons programadores escrevem código que humanos podem entender
>
> -- Martin Fowler

A solução que passa variáveis por referência parece inteligente (*clever*, porém esse termo também é usado para indicar exagero em tentar parecer inteligente, é algo negativo, é querer mostrar que sabe truques), mas no momento que você começa usar verá que não é tão boa assim. Sem falar que a solução da outra resposta está errada. Você terá que escrever tantos *overloads* que não compensará. O trabalho que dará para fazer essas opções será maior que o uso. A complicação não compensa, e e esquisitice torna o código menos legível sem ganho real algum. E mudanças vão te trazer problemas.

Se ainda insistisse pelo menos poderia fazer certo:

```
void boolReset(bool resetTo, ref bool b1, ref bool b2, ref bool b3) {
    b1 = b2 = b3 = resetTo;
}
```

Lembrando que se pode ter apenas uma variável terá mais um *overload*, se puder ser duas, precisará mais um, se tiver 4, outro. E considerando que tudo é o mesmo tipo e que não tem combinações.

Depois chama assim (vou colocar abaixo o original "por extenso" logo abaixo pra comparar o tamanho):

```
void resetStage() {
    boolReset(false, ref _fullLife, ref _halfLife, ref _almostDead);
}
void resetStage() {
    _fullLife = _halfLife = _almostDead = false;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Syntax/MultAssign.cs).

Mas ainda insisto, mesmo não conseguindo convencer, faça um em cada linha. Aumenta um `;` um <kbd>ENTER</kbd> e o `false` repetidos duas vezes, só isso, é muito pouco.

Tem um jeito que simplifica um pouco, mas não muito a sintaxe, mas aí a estrutura de dados ficará tão errada que nem vale a pena cogitar, e ainda bem que ninguém sugeriu.

Está olhando para as coisas erradas no código. Comece prestar atenção ao que importa.

Answer (score -1):

```
valueBool.All(x => x = resetTo);
```

Nem iria mudar o valor dos elementos do array dentro do próprio método, resultava se fosse para mudar o valor de uma propriedade:

```
valueBool.All(x => {x.propriedade = resetTo; return false;});
```

Podes usar overloads:

```
void boolReset(bool resetTo, out bool b1, out bool b2)
{
    b1 = b2 = resetTo;
}

void boolReset(bool resetTo, out bool b1, out bool b2, out bool b3)
{
    b1 = b2 = b3 = resetTo;
}
```